# nginx, imagescale gd function causes bug

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, php-gd

I am using the php-gd function imagescale on a server running nginx and php-fpm

When commenting it out, it works, if not, then it causes only this line in the error log:

```
recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: IP
```

and the IP is external.

I also googled about it and it *should* be related to php5-fpm and fastcgi config. Does anybody know anything concrete related to that function?

Thanks for any info or hint on what to look for.

**EDIT:**

I called the function like this:

```
imagescale($image,$width,$height, IMG_BICUBIC_FIXED);
```

found a bug listing page of php which told me that **IMG_BICUBIC_FIXED leaks memory.**
I used another mode and now it is working fine.

Comment: Your error message is from nginx, but it's acually meaningless. The real error message must be in `/var/log/php5-fpm.log` (or wherever your PHP-FPM writes to). Any hints in there?

Comment: well, I could not find that log, but I fixed it anyway (see under EDIT) :)